# Android extras getting lost on onBackPressed()

Tags: android, android-fragmentactivity

I'm attempting to save some data in intent, so when the user visits another screen or presses the **back button**, and comes back, the data persists. Essentially storing the state of a screen.

So you're in **Fragment 1**, you navigate to **Activity 2** (important data is here), if you leave **activity 2** by pressing back or through another way when you come back the data is still there.

***Here's where I start Activity 2 from Fragment 1***

```
intent = new Intent(getActivity(), DeliveryPageActivity.class);
...
startActivityForResult(intent,
```

***Here's where I'm currently trying the solve the problem***

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    //saving here (working okay)
    storeIntent.putExtra("currentDelivery", pageIndicatorView.getCurrentPage());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, storeIntent);
    super.onBackPressed();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    //restoring here (NOT WORKING, intent has no extras)
    if (storeIntent.hasExtra("currentDelivery")) {
        currentDelivery = storeIntent.getIntExtra("currentDelivery", currentDelivery);
        pageIndicatorView.setCurrentPage(currentDelivery, true);
    }
}
```

And starting a **new** intent in `onCreate()`

```
    storeIntent = new Intent();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try override onPause instead of onBackPressed in your Activity 2. See [docs for activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

Edit:
Sorry just tested. In your case, i would use SharedPreferences to restore
and override OnPause (get's called when back button is pressed) and onResume like this:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putInt("currentDelivery",pageIndicatorView.getCurrentPage());
    editor.apply();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences sp = this.getSharedPreferences("myPrefsName", MODE_PRIVATE);
    testState = sp.getInt("currentDelivery", 0);
}
```

Comment: thanks. I've tried using `protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` buts it's not being called when onBackPressed()

Comment: Sorry my initial answer was flawed. See under edit. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

call `finish();` instead of `super.onBackPressed()`

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //saving here (working okay)
    storeIntent.putExtra("currentDelivery", pageIndicatorView.getCurrentPage());
    setResult(RESULT_OK, storeIntent);
    finish();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to receive any data, then there is no meaning in using `startActivityForResult()` method. You can just use `startActivity()` method to open an activity.